# Sqlite throws "Unknown Tokenizer" exception after restarting app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, android-sqlite, android-room

I am packaging a custom Sqlite build in my app, with an HTMLtokenizer to use with FTS. I create the FTS table virtually with room.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subitem_content USING fts4(item_category_id, item_id, subitem_id, title, html, tokenize=HTMLTokenizer eng)
```

I also call the following:

```
System.loadLibrary("sqliteX")
```

to link the custom sqlite build and

```
System.loadLibrary("tokenizers")
```

to link the packaged Tokenizers library to the project.

I then register the tokenizer to the database with the following

```
sqliteDb.loadExtension("libtokenizers")
sqliteDb.registerTokenizer(Tokenizer.HTML_TOKENIZER)
```

This seems to work fine. I can insert data into the table and query the data just fine. That is until I close the app and restart it, where I receive the following error:

```
org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown tokenizer: HTMLTokenizer (code 1): , while compiling:
```

If I clear the app data and start again, things work just fine the first time,but crash upon restarting the app. 
I've checked /proc/pid/map to make sure the native libraries are loaded, and they show up there at the time of database transaction. Why would I get this error after restart?

Comment: At what place in the code are you calling `registerTokenizer`?

Comment: Right after creating the database. I have Room return an instance of SQLiteDatabase which has a  'post-create' callback. Inside that callback I call registerTokenizer on the database instance.

Comment: @DanielRust did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @davidm yes, following the accepted answers solution (load tokenizer/library in onConfigure callback)

Comment: @DanielRust can you add an answer with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the database only once, when you're running the app for the first time.
But the tokenizer must be available whenever you are using the database, so you must register it whenever you have a new database connection.

The proper place is wherever you create a new connection; in the original Android database API, this would be the [onConfigure callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)).

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I had ran into this issue mentioned in my question rather early in my software career. It was extremely frustrating to run into this issue and made me question whether I really wanted to be an engineer. When you responded to used the onConfigure() to load the library, and it worked, it was a game changer for me. Since then I have loved every aspect of my job. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question so long ago.